# Upload image put method with Restassured error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, rest-assured

First of all i share my api doc

[Document said image will send to header not body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY1tX.png)

And I wrote thsese codes

```
public Response uploadFile(){

    File upload = new File("senna.jpg");
    String uuid = getUuid();

    return given()
            .baseUri(getBaseUrl())
            .accept("application/json")
            .header("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate, br")
         //   .header("Content-Type","image/jpg")
            .contentType(ContentType.MULTIPART)

            .header("X-Auth-Token",payload.userAuth())
            .header("X-Meta-Strategy","1")
          //  .header("X-Object-Meta-File-Name",upload)
            .multiPart("X-Object-Meta-File-Name",upload,"image/jpg")
            .when().put("/"+uuid).then().log().all().assertThat().extract().response();

}
```

**This code upload an image with doc format not png.** So i tried multipart and .header() method both of them didn't work. If i use `.header("Content-Type","image/jpg")` & `.header("X-Object-Meta-File-Name",upload)` i got this error

Cannot serialize because cannot determine how to serialize content-type image/jpg

I know content type doesn't allow image/jpg.

So how can do that ? Thank you in advance

Comment: try remove `.contentType(ContentType.MULTIPART)` then re-run

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 uploaded a document format again :(

Comment: `Document said image will send to header not body` I cannot see that there is such a requirement

Comment: @AlexeyR. Thank you so muck you are right. Document is wrong because body have to be. Right now i am sharing the sollution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document was wrong and i added the `body(upload)`

```
public Response uploadFile(){

    File upload = new File("senna.jpg");
    String uuid = getUuid();

    return given()
            .baseUri(getBaseUrl())
            .accept("application/json")
            .header("Content-Type","image/jpg")
            .header("X-Object-Meta-File-Name","senna.jpg")
            .header("X-Auth-Token",payload.userAuth())
            .header("X-Meta-Strategy","1")
            .body(upload)
            .when().put("/"+uuid).then().log().all().assertThat().extract().response();

}
```

Thank you
Alexey R.